# Data from the db table is repeated while pulling

Tags: laravel, methods, implode

View

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<th>{{$user->name}}</th>
<th>{{$user->email}}</th>
<th>{{implode(', ',  $user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray())}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I should get the roles like this
admin
user

but i am getting as
admin,admin
user,user

Comment: use `array_unique()`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think your user have duplicated roles, you need to delete them, or make them unique.

Secondly, don't get data from db in view, use eager loading in your controller action:

```php
$users = User::where(...)->with('roles')->get();
```

In your View:

```php
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<th>{{$user->name}}</th>
<th>{{$user->email}}</th>
<th>{{implode(', ',  $user->roles->pluck('name')->unique()->toArray())}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ok it solved.i have done db:seed twise thats why the data was inserted twise.thanks

Comment: @AliRezaArju u'r welcome. Remember eager loading in your controller. That will reduce the n+1 query

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<td>{{$user->name}}</td>
<td>{{$user->email}}</td>
<td>{{$user->roles()->pluck('name')->implode(' ') }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```